# Deploy Apps with Ionic Package

Tags: android, npm, ionic-framework, package, command-line-interface

I figured i would try the 'new' CLI tool for Ionic, Package, but i am getting some weird errors that i haven't seen before.

When running the command :

```
  ionic package build android --profile release
```

The error i am getting

```
 undefined:0

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parse (native)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/io-config.js:179:28
at fs.js:271:14
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

After some research i found that this can happen when a command is run without sudo, but when running the command with sudo i am getting the dam error message.

Hopefully i am lucky and ill find an Ionic enthusiast who might help me with the matter. Couldn't find any Ionic related topics where this error was mentioned.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add `[]` to the .io-config.json file in the root directory of my ionic app.

Btw. dont forget to install `ionic add ionic-platform-web-client`

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way this error occured after I updated ionic which created this empty file..

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was annoyingly simple. In the file mentioned, find the line where CONFIG_BACKUP is defined and change it. You should see that it is:

```
var CONFIG_BACKUP = './.io-config.json'
```

It should actually be:

```
var CONFIG_BACKUP = './io-config.json'
```

I was building for iOS but had the same error as you which disappeared after the above.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error resulted from the config.xml file.  I would open all ionic files to make sure there are no formatting errors.  The rebuild